# objective-c: add view to window on button click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view

I'm new to objective-c so bear with me. This seems pretty simple but I must be doing something wrong. In IB I created an object, called it AppController and then added an action titled makeView and two IBOutlets, btnMakeView and mainWin, then connected everything properly and wrote the class file from that.

In AppController.h I have this code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface AppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow * mainWin;
    IBOutlet id btnMakeView;
}
- (IBAction)makeView:(id)sender;
@end
```

in AppController.m this code:

```
#import "AppController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation AppController
- (IBAction)makeView:(id)sender {

    //declare a new instance of viewcontroller, which inherits fromNSView, were going to allocate it with 
    //a frame and set the bounds of that frame using NSMakeRect and the floats we plug in.
    ViewController* testbox = [[ViewController alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 20.0)];

    //this tells the window to add our subview testbox to it's contentview
    [[mainWin contentView]addSubview:testbox];
}
-(BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

in ViewController.h I have this code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ViewController : NSView {
}
@end
```

and finally in ViewController.m I have this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController    
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    // Drawing code here.

    //sets the background color of the view object
    [[NSColor redColor]set];

    //fills the bounds of the view object with the background color
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}

@end
```

It compiles fine, there are no errors but  do not get an object, which I am assuming will be a rectangle, starting at x,y 10/10 and being 100x20. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add to this, I have logged the initWithFrame method of ViewController to make sure I am getting there and I am.

Comment: Note you can format lines as code by indenting them four spaces. The "101\n010" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. You can edit your post now and fix your formatting.

Comment: outis, thanks, every time I use the 101\n010 button for code it formats it crappily as you can tell. Not sure why. Didn't know about the indent but will use that going forward, as well as the accept answer function, also didn't know about that.

Comment: The code button behaves differently depending on whether or not there's any selected text, and whether or not all the lines are indented by at least 4 spaces. It acts as a toggle, switching between code (by indenting) and non-code (by unindenting). Tab characters are problematic. I recommend replacing all tabs in the source with four spaces (you can use a search-and-replace, or google for how to configure XCode to use spaces).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `mainWin` refer to a valid window? Other than that, your code works, though it could use some improvement. For example,

- `ViewController` is a view, not a controller, so it shouldn't be named a controller.
- You've got a memory leak. You never release the `ViewController` you create. The [memory management rules are very simple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH); read up on them.

Try the following changes. First, rename `ViewController` to `RedView` (or `SolidColorView` or somesuch). You can do this very simply by [refactoring](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/150-Refactoring/refactoring.html): [right-click](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/66) the class name in the `@interface` or `@implementation` declaration and choose "Refactor...".

In RedView.m:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    // the idiom is to call super's init method and test self all in the
    // same line. Note the extra parentheses around the expression. This is a 
    // hint that we really want the assignment and not an equality comparison.
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

In AppController.m:

```
- (IBAction)makeView:(id)sender {
    //declare a new instance of viewcontroller, which inherits fromNSView, were going to allocate it with 
    //a frame and set the bounds of that frame using NSMakeRect and the floats we plug in.
    RedView* testbox = [[RedView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 20.0)];

    //this tells the window to add our subview testbox to it's contentview
    // You don't need to keep a reference to the main window. The application already
    // does this. You might forget to hook up mainWin, but the following won't fail
    // as long as the app has a main window.
    [[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView] addSubview:testbox];
    // We're done with testbox, so release it.
    [testbox release];
}
```

Comment: Yes, mainWin is a valid window. Thanks for the help and the code improvements.

Comment: @PruitIgoe: does it work when you try the above `makeView`? If not, you'll need to try the debugger to see either what isn't defined or what's not getting executed.

Comment: I'm going to go and put myself in the stupid corner...I had given the window (in IB) the name mainWin, and in the AppController.h file I had IBOutlet NSWindow* mainWin...I took the name out of IB and everything worked fine...thanks for all the help.